# Notification not removed

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, swift4, viewwilldisappear

Using Swift4. In one of my ViewControllers I use some Notifications. The observer is in the ViewDidLoad. The calls are in a view that I lay over the VC. This for a generic menu.

When exiting the VC I call `NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)` to remove the notifications.

The Notifications point to a simple routine:

```
@objc func thisHandler() {
    print("This print statement appears")
}
```

Further in the app, I do some stuff and suddenly the print statement  above appears in the log.

I have tried to remove the observer both in: `viewWillDisappear`, `deinit` and even the `prepare:for segue:sender`. This message keeps apperearing. I have checked with other print statements that these routeines are executed.

This only occurs (afaik) when I have opened the Camera/Photo folder.
What am I missing?

Comment: Edit your question to include the code that calls `addObserver`.

Comment: Where do you add the observer?

Comment: Observer is in ViewDidLoad, the call to the observers are button triggered from a UIBUtton.

Comment: Try to remove the observer in `viewDidDisappear`.

Comment: @Anas, I did not think of that one before, so a good tip! However bad luck. It does not work.